# Sorting tuples in a list based on their product in Python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, product

Im trying to write a procedure to sort the tuples in a list based on their product value per tuple. I just tried sorting them first using a while loop but Im not able to integrate the multiplication of the numbers inside the tuple. The code I have so far is:

```
def sort_list (a):
    i = 0
    while i < len(a):
        key = i
        j = i + 1
        
        #first checking throuh the whole list if any number is bigger
        
        while j < len(a):
            if a[key] > a [j]:
                key = j
            j += 1
            
        #swap the numbers if the key one (i) is bigger than the j one the j one will be the new key
        # and swapped in the next section!
        
        a[i], a[key] = a[key], a[i]
        i += 1
    return a        

m = [(2, 3.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 2.5), (1, 1.0)]

sort_list(m)

print (m)

# should output : [(1, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (2, 3.0), (4, 2.5)]
```

Comment: Why not use the `list.sort` method?

Comment: for example, `m.sort(key=lambda x: x[0] * x[1])`

Comment: In python>=3.8 `import math; m.sort(key=math.prod)`

Comment: @Ch3steR I deleted my comment after re-reading your answer more carefully. You wrote `list.sort(m, key=...)` instead of `m.sort(key=...)`, which is a bit more unusual but not wrong. I posted my comment because when reading not carefully enough, I though you had called the list `list` and were sorting it using `list.sort(key=...)`. But that's not what you were doing. So I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 5):

The `list` class has a method `.sort` which sorts in-place and has a `key` argument to specify custom comparison.

- [**`list.sort`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

  > `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element (for example, `key=str.lower`). The `key` corresponding to each item in the list is calculated once and then used for the entire sorting process. The default value of `None` means that list items are sorted directly without calculating a separate key value.

### `Python >= 3.8`

In your case, we need to calculate the product of all the elements in the tuple. We can use [`math.prod`<sup>1</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/math.html#math.prod) similar to `sum`.

```
from math import prod

m = [(2, 3.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 2.5), (1, 1.0)]
m.sort(key=prod)
# list -> [(1, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (2, 3.0), (4, 2.5)]
```

[<kbd>**Online Demo**</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/z1o44o7cz)

I used `math.prod` to generalize the solution giving you the flexibility to use the solution on arbitrary length iterable.

### `Python < 3.8`

We can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) to generalize to make it work with arbitrary length iterable. The below code works in Python2.7 also.

```
from functools import reduce, partial
from operator import mul

prod = partial(reduce, mul)
m.sort(key=prod)
```

[<kbd>**Online Demo**</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/P3MY8x1rb)

---

<sub>1. [`math.prod` is available from *python3.8*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#math)</sub>

Comment: Neat! I was hoping there was something for the mult in the stdlib, and looks like `math.prod` fits the bill here.

Comment: @rv.kvetch They added it very recently. It's available from python3.8 That may be the reason it's not used widely yet :)

Comment: @Ch3steR It's over two years old already.

Comment: @KellyBundy True. In my defence, the walrus operator stole all the attention. :P and `math.prod` was at the middle of the what's new page(that too only one line). Again I might be wrong that it's not known widely. I just commented from my limited knowledge.

Comment: @Ch3steR Well I do suspect it's not known widely, yes :-). I guess I misunderstood your earlier comment, sounded to me like people don't use `math.prod` because they don't use 3.8 yet (and I hope most of us use 3.8+ by now... )

Comment: @KellyBundy Apologies, not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) or [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with [key argument](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)**

Since Python 3.8 there is a function [math.prod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) which can calculate the product of items in a tuple. You can use it as the key argument like that:

```
import math.prod
m = [(2, 3.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 2.5), (1, 1.0)]
list.sort(m, key=math.prod)
print(m)
```

Prior to Python 3.8 you can accomplish that with lambda (or any other function):

```
m = [(2, 3.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 2.5), (1, 1.0)]
list.sort(m, key=lambda x: x[0] * x[1])
print(m)
```

The difference between [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) is that [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) is changing m in place so you don't have to assign it to m again. If you use [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) on the other hand, the sorted list is beeing returned as a new list so you would have to assign it t m.

Answer (score 0):

`list.sort` and `sorted` both let you specify a `key` argument, which should be a function giving a "score" which will be used for sorting. In your case, we just have to make this score the product of the tuple elements:

```py
sorted(m, key=lambda x: x[0]*x[1])
```